# SQlite Cipher IOS

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, sqlite

[This here i have shared to show that i have `Sqlite` file present in copy bundle resources :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrcjX.png) I am using Sqlitecipher in my `iOS` app when run my app in `Simulator` (offline) it shows all of the data successfully and every query works fine like **(update,delete,insert**) but when testing my app on device it doesn't shows up anything. Following way i tried it :

1. Saved `Sqlite` file in bundle
2. Copied `Sqlite` file from bundle to `Document` `Directory`
3. Delete app from `Simulator` and reset my `Simulator` but i am still facing the same issue. Kindly suggest solution ( its a **Salesforce native App** )

This is the code to get file from bundle to `Document Directory` in `Appdelegate`:`

```
   func copyFile()
    {
        var documents: NSString
        documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

        let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LeadWork1", ofType: "sqlite")
        print(bundlePath, "\n") //prints the correct path
        let destPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let fullDestPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: destPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent("LeadWork1.sqlite")
        let fullDestPathString = fullDestPath.path
        print(fullDestPathString)
        print(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(bundlePath!)) // prints true


        if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(bundlePath!) == true
        {
            print("File Exist")

        }
       else
        {
            do{
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath!, toPath:   [enter image description here][1]fullDestPathString!)
            }catch{
                print("\n")
                print(error)
            }
        }

        let error  = sqlite3_open(fullDestPathString!, &database)
        if error != SQLITE_OK
        {

            print("Error while opening");
        }
        else
        {
            // print(fileForCopy)
            print(destPath)
            print("already open");
        }

    }`
```

**Help will be appreciated!**

Comment: You would need to share some code to get an answer here?

Comment: Where do you actually use the cipher, and decrypt the database?

Comment: @max_ I have followed steps mentioned in this Url (https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/ ) to integrate sqlite cipher in my project . And build is succeeded.For now i am using sqlite cipher as normal database without encryption key. The Create Insert and Select Queries are working fine in Simulator but not in device. Thanks in advance. Let me know if anything else is required to resolve my Issue.

Comment: @Ichthyocentaurs i added the code as asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Enable  following :

Select Project -> Build Setting -> Architecture Tab - > Build Release to YES

Make sure to enable Both Debug and Release to **YES**.

It will solve your issue .